# Samsung NP305U1A laptop won't resume from suspension

Tags: 12.04, suspend, samsung

I just bought a Samsung NP305U1A laptop and installed Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 LTS on it.

Whenever I suspend the computer and try to wake it back up, the monitor only shows a black screen and the only thing I can do is a hard reset.

Kernel: 3.2.0-24-generic

Graphic: Radeon HD 6320

Anybody know what to do?

**UPDATE**

I did some some research and remebered that I installed the "ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver" from the "Additional drivers" software bundled in Ubuntu.

I also tried to install the "ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver (post-release updates)" but whenever I do, it gives me an error and I can't continue

So I decided to make a clean install of Ubuntu 12.04 again and **when i tried the suspension out-of-the-box, it did work**.

But since I can't install the drivers I need, HD video is choppy like hell.

So perhaps the suspension bug was fixed in the post-release updates of the driver, but sadly I cannot install them, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify which graphics card drivers are you using. With your graphics card it can be either the open source ones, embedded into the kernel, or the proprietay ones that come with the Catalyst management software.

If you are using the proprietary ones, I suggest you try and uninstall them; then you can test wether it was their fault or not.

If you didn't install the Catalyst suite, you can [download it here](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx) to make the reverse test.

Tell us how it went. :-)

Comment: Will download and report back!

Comment: Question updated. :)

Comment: Since this was the solution to the original question, I'll mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Xubuntu on an Acer Timeline Aspire. Uninstalling the ATI Catalyst appears to have  solved the problem. The laptop now resumes after hitting the space bar and requests the password; once entered the system is again fully operational.